# Import from mysqldump not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got an sql dump generated from mysqldump. This file includes mysql-version specific comments (`/*!{MySQL version number} {Code} */`).
If I insert an sql syntax error after this block, PDO doesn't trigger an exception.

php code

```
$sql = file_get_contents('FooBar.sql');
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=FooBar', 'root');
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec($sql);
```

FooBar.sql

```
/*!40101 SET @Foo='Bar' */;
ERROR
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('Bar');
```

This executes without causing any exceptions or errors. If I either remove the `/*!40101 SET @Foo='Bar' */;` statement, or move the error on line up an PDOException is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the hek2mgl's for putting me on the right path.

PDO doesn't support multiple queries. If you execute a statement containing multiple queries, they get executed, but it seems PDO stops behaving after the first query is executed. The `/*!{MySQL version number} {Code} */` style comment gets executed as a regular query by MySql and anything after this gets ignored by PDO, even though it gets executed by MySql.

The same error indicated would trigger by the following query:

```
SET @Foo='Bar';
ERROR
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('Bar');
```

To make this work using PDO, I need to split up the statements.

```
$sql = file_get_contents('FooBar.sql');
$lines = explode(';', $sql);
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=FooBar', 'root');
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $trimmedLine = trim($line, " \t\n\r\0\x0B");
    if (strlen($trimmedLine) > 0) {
        $pdo->exec($trimmedLine.';');
    }
}
```

EDIT:

An alternative solution is to use pdo prepared statements.

```
$sql = file_get_contents('FooBar.sql');
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=FooBar', 'root');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
do {
    ... Do stuff ...
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
if ($stmt->errorCode() != '00000') {
    ... Handle error ...
}
```

Comment: That's not correct. Of course PDO supports multiple queries. Try `SELECT 1 AS num; SELECT 1 AS num;`.

Comment: If you insert an error between the queries, it'll get swallowed by PDO and the remaining statement will not get executed. If I try multiple statements in a single query, only data from the first query will be returned (errorcode, rows affected, etc).

Comment: It seems that you are right. PDO allows multi queries but fails to handle errors correctly, or in better words, fails to report them to the client. I've update my post. you can use `Mysqli`

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `;` at the end of the comment. I don't know why at the moment. Will investigate further...

Found this [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65230). But don't expect the char encoding to be a problem as I've investigated the network traffic using `wireshark` and the MySQL returns a Syntax error (as expected.) Still don't know why PDO doesn't handle this correctly.

---

A workaround would be to use `Mysqli` which seems to handle this properly. The following example demonstrates this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'secret');

$result = $pdo->query('
SELECT 1 AS num;
ERROR
SELECT 1 AS num;
');

if(!$result) {
    var_dump($pdo->errorInfo); // silence ...
}

$mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'user', 'secret');
$result = $mysqli->query('
SELECT 1 AS num;
ERROR
SELECT 1 AS num;
');

if(!$result) {
    print( $mysqli->error);
    // Output: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ERROR SELECT 1 AS num' at line 2
}
```

Comment: You have to use `mysqli->multi_query` or it will fail on the second statement. But then you have to iterate all rowsets to detect errors.

Comment: Might be, will validate this. Btw, why not using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/load-data.html) ?

Comment: In my project, the database might still change. I want to minimize duplicate config and specific db dependencies. The PDO connection is generated from the framework (Symfony/Doctrine). My data comes from a mysqldump, and includes several tables. If I change database now, all I have to change are the shell script for generating the sqldump.

Comment: Ok, understood. While your answer might be a working solution for you (+1), I still think that this is a bug. You should consider to file it or extend an existing bug report. (Very interesting question, thanks ;) I'll add the `doctrine` tag. Maybe we'll get more answers...